# Independent analog sensors have dependent readings?

Tags: sensor, adc, analog, stm32f4, sampling

I was working with a Nucleo f411re (STM32 MCU) in order to read several analog sensors.
I started testing a single temperature sensor (LM35) and all was fine. 
When I added a linear potentiometer for reading its extension, a strange fact happened: **the temperature read increased proportionally to the extension of the potentiometer.** Here's the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJqulH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

PA0 and PA1 are analog pins, connected to stm32 ADC. [Here](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/3f/4c/a4/82/bd/63/4e/92/CD00211314/files/CD00211314.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00211314.pdf) you can find the ADC datasheet.

So I measured the output voltage from LM35 with multimeter and it was stable even when I was extending the potentiometer; while, if read from Nucleo, the temperature was "following" the potentiometer read.

I solved this problem adding a 1 µF capacitor between ground and the V_out of LM35. But I'm not satisfied, because I would like to know the reason of the strange temperature read behavior. Any Idea?

**EDIT**:
I have found something that could explain this problem at section 3.4.1 of the ADC datasheet. It seems a known issue, due to the sampling switch in the internal sampling circuit of the ADC. Can you confirm this?

Comment: We need a schematic diagram. There's an button on the editor toolbar. Click it! "_When I added a linear potentiometer ..._" How can we possibly guess where you added it?

Comment: Please post your code also.

Comment: Probably your sample time was too short for the impedance of the sensor, and you read it immediately after the pot (I'm assuming it's got a single ADC multiplexed to pins)

Comment: @pjc50, I think is somewhat in ADC the problem. Can you explain me your hypothesis?

Comment: @Bernheart These devices typically uses a multiplexed ADC, the datasheet will have details. You have not given us the datasheet, so we have to do additional work to help _you_. That's why we can only guess and hint.

Comment: @pipe, sorry, I could not imagine the nature of the problem. Is in my interest to keep you in condition to help me

Comment: Well, with a datasheet and a circuit diagram, this is now a good and upvotey question.

Comment: If your wires to the LM35 are long you must follow the datasheet recommendations to prevent instability.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, no the wire are really short.

Comment: There is no datasheet at your link.

Comment: @ScottSeidman try now

Comment: @ScottSeidman: that isn't the datasheet of the ADC, but it is a more helpful document in this case: a troubleshooting document for the ADC.

Comment: There is no ground on your micro. Is there one in the real version? Both LM35 and pot should be connected to it.

Comment: @Transistor of course no, my STM32 is connected to ground!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of things that could be causing this problem.  [see here](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/3f/4c/a4/82/bd/63/4e/92/CD00211314/files/CD00211314.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00211314.pdf).  However, what appears to be the most obvious is a problem with sampling time.

If you check out page 35, it mentions that the ADC is a sample and hold converter:  it has a capacitor that charges (or discharges) until it has the same voltage as the source, then it reads that value.  The time for this is set by the time that SW1 is on: the "sampling time".  If there isn't enough time for the capacitor to discharge/charge to the correct voltage before turning off the switch and reading the value (depending on the resistance of the source), then you won't get the right value.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDjoLl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is in the section on problems with reading high impedance sources.  The [LM35](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf) has a low impedance output **if** it is sourcing current, it can only sink 1µA of current though, which makes it a very high impedance current sink.

If you are setting a higher voltage with the pot than you are reading from the LM35, then the current from the capacitor needs to flow out of C_sh through the LM35:  this is very slow (because of that 1µA current sink capability), and thus your sampling time is too short.

A capacitor helps to smooth this out, but also slows down the response time of the LM35.

A quick fix is to put a >1kΩ resistor in parallel with the LM35.  This sinks current when you need it to, and gives a current path to ground for the current from C_sh.

Comment: Thank you! But I haven't understood how a capacitor can help to resolve this problem: in fact how can an external capacitor reduce the discharging time of C_sh?

Comment: A few explanations: 1) when the switch is initially attached, the external capacitor looks like a short to the fast transient of the higher voltage of C_sh, so a lot of the current will flow out rapidly that way.  The lower frequency components of the transient are smaller and can flow out via the LM35.  2) you have a larger capacitor than C_sh on the output.  When the two are put in parallel, all the charge is evenly distributed between them.  Since the output capacitor is larger, it soaks up the extra charge from the internal capacitor and barely changes its voltage.